# jqPlot: Are overlapped bar charts possible?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

An example probably describes what I want to achieve most easily.

If I have, for example, the series [80, 70] and [90, 90], I want the first of the stacked bars to have the first series' color from 0 to 80, and then the other series' color from 80-90. Right now I get them on top of each other, resulting in a 170 units high bar.

The Javascript code:

```
plot3 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [normalSeries, distSeries], {
        stackSeries: true,
        captureRightClick: true,
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barMargin: 20,
                barWidth: 10,
                highlightMouseDown: true
            },
            pointLabels: { show: true }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: schoolNames
            },
            yaxis: {
                padMin: 0
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'e',
            placement: 'outside'
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the only way to solve this problem to write a "fork" of the BarRenderer.js? Is there another plotting tool that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be done, using some pre-processing of data. But I am intrigued as to why this would be required in first place?. Just in case, if the second series point value is smaller than first, then how would that be visible unless, you intend to help user only through reversed display colors?

To me, stacking is plain simple: a sits atop b - no matter what their individual values are.
If you use roundabout to achieve your "requirement", my best guess would be that the user would be confused.

You may possibly want to look at other options: [Jqplot different kinds of rendering in one chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375459/jqplot-different-kinds-of-rendering-in-one-chart)